# Text Selector/Analyser using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

Trying to create text analyzer for a team so they can check our emails before we send them out. The idea is to get all the team to participate in choosing the best emails that are sent out to clients:

I've used the following code in the HTML:

```
  <p class="sentence" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor,  adipisicing elit.</p>
  <div class="popup-inner" data-popup="popup-1" hidden="hidden">
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="like" checked> Like<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="dislike"> Dislike<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
       <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
  </div>
```

And using the following code to run it:

```
var sentence = $('.sentence').html().split(/\s+/),
    result = [];

for( var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++ ) {
    result[i] = '<span class="keyword-btn" data-popup="' + i + '">' + sentence[i] + '</span>';
}

$('.sentence').html(result.join(' '));

$('.sentence').on('click', 'span', function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});

function showPopup(span, $popup) {
  var offset = span.offset();
  $popup
    .fadeIn(350)
    .css({
      left: Math.min(offset.left, $(window).innerWidth()-$('.questions').outerWidth()) + 25,
      top: offset.top + 50
    });
}

$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('span.keyword-btn').on('click', function(e)  {
        //var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        //$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
         showPopup($(this), $('div.popup-inner'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And here's my CSS code:

```
.sentence span:hover, .highlight{
    color: rgb(58, 207, 222);
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:5px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I need to get the radio buttons to appear just under each selected word but failing till now. A little help would be great please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you missing is a position for **.popup-inner**

```
.popup-inner {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#c1cecb;
}
```

That should get your box of buttons under each selected word.